# linux: recursively copy directory with rsync excluding all containing a specific string

Tags: linux, recursion, copy, rsync

I am looking to recursively copy directory with rsync excluding all containing a specific string. I have tried:

```
rsync -aP --exclude='stringname' /source /destination
```

but it only excludes the file names with an exact match. Is there a way to exclude all files and folders with 'stringname'?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
rsync -aP --exclude='*stringname*' /source /destination
```

Just added `*` at the beginning and the end of the string... and that worked!